# How to stop media player on AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-mediaplayer

How to make stop media player on AlertDialog (with setCancelable ( true )) How to make, when i touch the screen. Alertdialog gone and mediaplayer is stop ?

```
faktaunik.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder jawaban = new AlertDialog.Builder (     new ContextThemeWrapper (BadakActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
            jawaban.setTitle ( "FAKTA UNIK HEWAN" )

                    .setMessage ( "Ayam punya sejumlah kemampuan yang unik dan hebat. Misalnya, ayam bisa bernavigasi alias menentukan arah dengan bantuan matahari. Ayam juga bisa melihat sinar ultraviolet, suatu kemampuan yang tidak dimiliki manusia.\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "Ayam juga punya pendengaran yang bagus, dan mereka bisa memperbaiki pendengaran mereka sendiri. Jika pendengaran mereka mulai berkurang, ayam tinggal menumbuhkan sel pendengaran yang baru hingga kembali ke kondisi nyaris 100 persen. Dan ayam ternyata bisa terbang cukup jauh, dengan rekor terbang selama 13 detik dan mencapai jarak 92 meter.\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "Nah, itulah fakta menakjubkan tentang ayam yang mungkin baru kamu tahu. Gimana, ternyata hewan yang biasa kita lihat seperti ayam pun punya sejumlah fakta menarik bukan? Yuk kita terus pelajari alam sekitar kita yang menarik ini." )
                    .setCancelable ( true );



            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog dialog = jawaban.create ();
            dialog.show ();

            stopPlaying ();
            mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(BadakActivity.this, R.raw.faktabadak);
            mp1.start();

        }
    } );
```

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: you can add DissmisListener to AlertDialog and stop media player after dismiss